# openssl's RSA_public_decryption has different results in x86 and arm

Tags: gcc, openssl

the same public key embedded in the my program as char array, got different key sizes in x86 (256 bytes) and in ARM926 (252 bytes) returned from RSA_size().  256 is the expected one and indeed worked well on x86 and of course failed in ARM when calling RSA_public_decryption() as shown below.

```
unsigned char pubkbuf[] = 
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1E+0NuRsVNULh3SFsTvV\n"
"7vFrDs97YvrCFvLc01ZTE79CW8LokGoYhQUwhM+nuD4+JlpozTwVCNHOfp31thrt\n"
"vAwKmGLIi2UpGUJktTCHcB8lcP0xMY8+Q1Z/l4N5LP7LvHozXrlws8dEtOvJiPez\n"
"pQCuBoKl6Xpr8tHHiLiALaXueWhJ7xxuyZZUyk8xWbQufiqXz+MFJImLHQOyC9zc\n"
"W64QG0lu4QqLBOA/QzuuIbdZqPcydH+pW1GWBuPEVBe3nxooTSBl+R0xHZPzGCdq\n"
"GhecCciJLFtt8/C+05teXDWCPBSqJqZv47l1zEIiqjKWJ5k8A9yx76+EpcGN1Cx9\n"
"CQIDAQAB\n"
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
;

int ksz = sizeof (pubkbuf);

bio = BIO_new_mem_buf (pubkbuf,ksz);

RSA* rsapubkey = RSA_new();

PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bio, &rsapubkey, NULL, NULL);

dump_buffer_hex (rsapubkey,272);

printf("key size= %d\n", (RSA_size(rsapubkey));

hdrbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc (RSA_size(rsapubkey));

hdrsz = RSA_public_decrypt (sigsz, sigbuf,
                            hdrbuf,
                            rsapubkey,
                            RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

have tried different versions of compiler, gcc-4.1 / gcc-4.7 (with/without -m32 x86) and different versions of libcrypto, libssl (32 and 64 bits in x86). all got the same result. need your help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a few missing brackets, I got 256 bytes in 32bit mode on a mac and segfault in 64bit mode.

I found that adding

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
```

fixed the segfault and got me 256. Surprising!

At first I suspected the extra nul byte you were counting with `sizeof(pubkbuf)` (you can pass -1 to `BIO_new_mem_buf` to get it to do a `strlen` for you). Then I thought maybe you should have been using the return value of `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` instead of the second arg, although I can't find any doco on that function anywhere.

So the #include is my best guess.

OpenSSL looks to be a barrel of laughs.

Comment: Adding `#include`s doesn't magically solve segmentation faults... at least not in my world.

Comment: Life and the C language are full of surprises!